# Boostrap Multiselect condition if checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I have one array with values, and i make a request this send informations to multiselect.

When i open my select, i have a couple values pre-selected.

My problem is, if i click to unchecked a checkbox on the boostrap multiselect, i wanna remove this information from my array. If i click in the checkbox i wanna put the value back in the array.

In my code i first check if the value is in the array, but the interaction with the boostrap select isn't what i want to do.

```
    // that bring the information in boostrap multiselect
    var vetornovo = ValueChecked();

    // here i try to detect the change to check and unchecked but doesnt works
    // all informations is selected: "selected" by default
    $("#os-select-list").change(function() {
                // i take the checkbox value.
                var valueck = parseInt($("#os-select-list option:selected").text());

                // if the information is in that i array when i click to unchecked then remove.
                  if (vetornovo.indexOf(valueck) > -1) {
                        index = $.inArray(valueck, vetornovo);
                        vetornovo.splice(index, 1);  
                        console.log(vetornovo);     
                    // when i click to selecte the value again i push and insert back to the array.
                  } else {
                    vetornovo.push(valueck);
                    console.log(vetornovo);   
                  }
    });
```

i wanna understand what is wrong, why when i click on the checkbox doensn't do and some times duplicated the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you are using 
https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect.html

the command to detect change is

```
* Triggered on change of the multiselect.
*
* Not triggered when selecting/deselecting options manually.
*
* @param {jQuery} option
* @param {Boolean} checked 
*/
onChange : function(option, checked) {

}
```

not 'change' as you have in your code

There are many 'selects' that work with bootstrap - I like https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/ - it has good examples and easy to read instructions - worth a look if you are just starting out...

Comment: onChange : function(option, checked) {
}
Doesn't works for me because my multi-select construct is in HTML and the code is in .js.
i'll try to transfer the multi-select to .js file.

  $('#os-select-list').multiselect({
   enableFiltering: true,
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
   nonSelectedText: '',
   allSelectedText: '.',
   maxHeight: 400,
   enableClickableOptGroups : true
        });

Comment: You should construct your code (yes, in javascript.. - just like your example showed....) like http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onChange.  If you want more help, you need to show the code you have in ValueChecked() as well.  I think you just need to configure your logic better, but I don't get the full picture yet.  Also, I don't understand what you mean that "multi-select construct is in HTML" - that's not possible as it clearly is JS.....  Again, show all your code and you can get help.

Comment: This Works haha